# Did not understand the code with conversion of the loop to a list in python

Tags: python

I am a novice in python, and got this code:

```
nlist = autoscaling_connection.get_all_launch_configurations()
name = "CONFIG"    
versions = [x.name[len(name):] for x in nlist
                if (x.name.startswith(name) and is_number(x.name[len(name):]))]
```

I understand that the for loop is concatenated into the versions list but I do not understand the assignment:

```
[x.name[len(name):]
```

Comment: What is `name`? It's defined externally. What about `nlist`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist that doesn't matter here too much, as he is simply asking about the syntax of the list comprehension. (although it would if he was trying to provide a MVCE) :)

Comment: Sure. I'm promoting him to ask clearer questions, but not insisting on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: added the definition of nlist and name

Comment: It's doing a search by name like e.g. `max` and expects the format `max1234` for items in `nlist`. Eventually you will have a list (`versions`) only containing `'1234'` (sticking to my example). So if `nlist` also contained `max4321`, `versions` would look like this: `['1234', '4321']`.

Comment: Hi @Alex, is there anything else you would like explaining? (you haven't accepted an answer I assume you forgot or would like something else explaining)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll expand the whole code, then go through it

```
versions = [x.name[len(name):] for x in nlist
            if (x.name.startswith(name) and is_number(x.name[len(name):]))]
```

is equivilent to

```
versions = []
for x in nlist:
    if (x.name.startswith(name) and is_number(x.name[len(name):])):
         versions.append(x.name[len(name):])
```

as for what

```
x.name[len(name):]
```

means, it means to take from x.name, the characters starting at the index which is equal to `len(name)` (the length of name), to the end of the `x.name`

so in a simpler example, say I have a list

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and I do

```
my_list[2:]
```

then this would return

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

which is the same as from the 2th element to the end.

I hope this helps. If you want to learn more about python slice notation, I can recommend this other SO question: [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: 2th? Nice :). +1 just for that. Except index 2 is the 3th element. You should probably fix that.

Answer (score 0):

In python if `x` is a list and `i` is an index (an integer).

```
x[i:]
```

means "all item in `x` starting at index `i` all the way to the end"

You can also have

```
x[i:j]
```

"all item in `x` starting at index `i` all the way to, but not including `j`"

```
x[:j]
```

"all item in `x` starting at beginning all the way to, but not including `j`"

```
y = x[:]
```

"copy all elements of x in a new list and assign it to y"

```
y = x[2:9:3]
```

"every third element of x starting at index 2 and ending before index 9."

There are more I'd suggest looking up list properties in Python.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more complete (but guesstimated) code:

```
class K:
    """A class that has a name property"""
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

# a prefix to look for            
name = "Fiat "


# a list of objects that have a name - some starting with our name
nlist = [K("Fiat 2"), K("Fiat 4"), K("Fiat 2711999"), K("Fiat Dupe 09"), K("DosntFly 0815")]

def is_number(text):
    """Test if the text is an integer."""
    try:
        int(text.strip())
    except:
        return False
    return True


versions = [x.name[len(name):] for x in nlist
                if (x.name.startswith(name) and is_number(x.name[len(name):]))]

print(versions)
```

Output:

```
['2', '4', '2711999']
```

Why?

The list comprehension test each element of `nlist`.

It will let only things into `versions` that statisfy the `if (x.name.startswith(name) and is_number(x.name[len(name):]`.

Meaning: each classes instanse `name` has to start with the variable `name`'s content **and** whatever comes after as many characters as `name` got, has to check as `True` if fed to `is_number()`.

If this fits, it is taking the "number-part" and adds it as element into the resulting list.

```
"Fiat Dupe 09"  # not in the list, because "Dupe 09" is not True
"DosntFly 0815" # not in the list, because not starting with "Fiat "
```